# Installation error when commanding pip install d3 on my virtualenv

Tags: python

When I commanded `pip install d3` to install the package, I got the following error.

```
(upload) Seungchului-MacBook-Pro:upload sclee$ pip3 install d3
Collecting d3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/20/aee1da98c819523d1c36f32232f28045cddba6f3411094fa5aa548f3db74/d3-0.1.0.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/w7/1l0pttwd5yg7nqn1j53l33mh0000gn/T/pip-install-kswsp3yr/d3/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 897, in open
        file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/w7/1l0pttwd5yg7nqn1j53l33mh0000gn/T/pip-install-kswsp3yr/d3/README.rst'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w7/1l0pttwd5yg7nqn1j53l33mh0000gn/T/pip-install-kswsp3yr/d3/
```

To resolve the issue, I tried to google it and found that `pip install -U setuptools` would solve the issue, however it didn't work to my case.
I also tried to command it by `sudo` but result is same.

My python version is `3.6.5`. What is the problem? I need your help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the pip3 command since you are using python 3.6.5 the command would be as follows:

```
pip3 install js.d3
```

Then once that is successful you can use the following:

```
from js.d3 import d3
d3.need()
```

This was straight from the Python Software Foundation Page which can be found here:[Python_Software_Foundation_Page](https://pypi.org/project/js.d3/)

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for **pip3 install js.d3**
and use like- from js.d3 import d3